Random Position Particle Generation within a volume

I struggle with particle animation using Keyed physics within assigned objects volume.
My question is that the first particle generation in the starting volume is unnatural like the attachments.
As those images show, the current volume seems separated into 4 sections and the assigned particles start filling out within those boundaries instead of natural distribution over the entire volume.


I can't find how to change this option, what I only know so far is changing some values and options in the Emitter > Source > Distribution (Random) section. But it doesn't work so far..

Could you share your solution to make this better?
Thank you for your insight in advance..
Problem

Impossible to know the answer without more details about your setup and settings.

Thank you for your comment Harry, I have attached more images and setup that I made for better understanding. Please let me know if you think this is not sufficient to convey the issue.

I think I have solved this, I just re-make the setup and system with the same process I did. And now it works as I wanted. I guess there might be an error or bug in the data processing..?
